# Cannot add calculation field to clientdataset

Tags: delphi, runtime, field, addition, tclientdataset

I am trying to add a calculation field to an existing data set created with `fieldDefs.add` using the code below with many variations I found on several sites including stack overflow.

But the `fieldDefs` created by the `fieldDefs` line or by the `dataSet` line are lost on update by `FieldDefs.count`.

`Fields.counts` persist but are not saved to XML files.

No exceptions are raised.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?
Thanks

```
MYclientDataSet.CreateDataSet;
MYclientDataSet.open;
MYclientDataSet.FieldDefs.Update;
MYclientDataSet.Active := False;
for i := 0 to MYclientDataSet.FieldDefs.Count - 1 do
    MYclientDataSet.FieldDefs[i].CreateField(MYclientDataSet);
fld := TStringField.Create(MYclientDataSet);
with fld do begin
     FieldName := 'PartSummary';
     FieldKind := fkCalculated;
     Calculated := True;
     Name := cds.Name + FieldName;
     DataSet := MYclientDataSet;
     MYclientDataSet.FieldDefs.Add('PartSummary', ftString, 30, false);
     MYclientDataSet.FieldDefs.update;
end;
MYclientDataSet.active := true;
MYclientDataSet.open;
MYclientDataSet.edit;
```

Comment: Why do you need to open twice? That may not be the issue, and it could be needed or harmless. But it seems strange.

Comment: You should add all the fields you require , including calculated ones, before calling `CreateDataSet`.

Comment: I've never called `update` again after adding a calculated field..I believe `update` opens the table and closes it, so in this one routine, you open the table three times... don't open it until your done. and `active := true` and `open` do the same thing, so choose one (I prefer `open`).

Answer (score 1):

According to Cary Jensen in the Delphi education link [Defining a Clientdataset's Structure...](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29001)  you cannot create a calculated, lookup, aggregate field using FieldDefs.  You must use TFields instead.

Comment: Indeed.  I've never found that it's worthwhile messing around with FieldDefs and always just work with the DataSet's Fields collection instead.  Using FieldDefs just provides an opportunity for them to get out of synch with the Fields' definitions.