# TFDMemtable FieldDefs does not consider lookup fields?

Tags: delphi, memory-table

Using Delphi 10.2.3, I dropped in a form a Firedac `TFDMemTable` component which was   I used Field Editor to define 5 fields, one of those fields is a Lookup Field  (`FieldKind = fkLookup`) .

I created a code to scan all fields of the `MemSource` MemTable to add those fields in a `MemDestination` Memtable.

I had a problem in scan the `MemSource.FieldDefs` because its total number of fields did not consider the Lookup one !   See the code :

```
    procedure TFormA.BTCopyFieldsClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
       i         : integer;
    begin

      for I := 0 to MemSource.FieldDefs.Count-1 do
      begin
            if (memSource.Fields.Fields[i].FieldKind = FkData) then
                memDestination.FieldDefs.Add (
                         memSource.FieldDefs.Items[i].DisplayName,
                         memSource.FieldDefs.Items[i].DataType,
                         memSource.FieldDefs.Items[i].Size,
                         memSource.FieldDefs.Items[i].Required
                         )
           Else

                ShowMessage( GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TFieldKind),
                             Integer(memSource.FieldDefs.Items[i].Datatype)
                           );

           memDestination.CreateDataSet;
           memDestination.CopyDataSet(memSource,[coRestart, coAppend]);
      end;
   end;
```

I realized that `memSource.FieldDefs.Count` had 4 fields only,  it missed the 5th one which was a lookup type .

However `memSource.Fields.Count` accounts for 5 fields, that is correct.

**The questions are :**

1. Is lookup field defined at design time considered in `FieldDefs` ?
   (if it is not considered,  so WHY ?)
2. Why `memSource.FieldDefs.Count` is different from `memSource.Fields.Count` ?
   (i.e.  I have more fields in the memtable than in its definition )

Am I doing somethinf wrong in the above code ?   What ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: FieldDefs are the underlying table fields and Fields are the Delphi side and can include lookups and calculated fields which are not part of the underlying database table.

Comment: This point has cropped up before and is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073142/cannot-add-calculation-field-to-clientdataset/48997060

Comment: @Brian, thanks for the explanation. I tested an inclusion of a calculated field in a TFDmemtable  and this field appeared in the FieldDefs too, besides the fields of the related databse table.  Do you know the reason why calculated fields appear in FieldDefs  while lookup does not ?

Comment: @MartinA, thks for the thread reference.  Based on that thread, do you know if it is possible to scan  a dataset.fields collection and identify if a field is a lookup, calculated or table based ?